# Terminal not showing current directory nor user@machine

Tags: terminal, directory, mobaxterm

I recently updated bioconda and after the update, I noticed that I no longer see the current directory nor `username@localmachine` on my terminal.

Before, my terminal would show something like:

```
(base)[username@login01 ~]$
```

Now all I see is `(base)`.

Note: I'm on my university's computing cluster, so I can't edit `.bashrc` (which seems like an answer from other posts).

I can get it back using `export PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '` but when I activate a conda environment, the problem arises again. Before I would see `(environment_name)[username@login01 ~]$` but now I only see `(environment_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to type was `conda init bash`